# Difference between value.x and value[x] (getting property from array) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties

I'm reading [this part of Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html#p_etK6gD7WXZ), and got stuck with the properties.

It said that

> Both `value.x` and `value[x]` access a property on value—but not necessarily the same property.
>
> ......
>
> Whereas `value.x` fetches the property of value named “x”, `value[x]` tries to evaluate the expression x and uses the result as the property name.

(`value` is an array and `x` is property like `.length` in this example.)

What's the difference between `value.x` and `value[x]`? I don't know how `value[x]` *evaluate* expression.

Comment: `value.x` means `x` in value. In the second one. `x` is a variable. So if x is equal to a then value[x] is equal to value.a

Comment: So it's like myArray.length === myArray[length] ? Which may be better to use usually? (like better efficiency in computing or human-friendly)

Comment: myArray[length] is invalid unless you have a variable names "length" with the value of "length" dot notation is always better practice

Comment: `value.x` is same as `value['x']`

just have a look at this simple example you will understand

   

     var a={'id':1, 'name':'xyz'};
        console.log("a.id==", a.id, "a.name==", a.name)
        console.log("a['id']==", a['id'], "a['name']==", a['name'])

if you will simply put `a[id]` , it will try to evaluate id  and results in error `id is not defined`

Comment: Thanks all! One more to ask... for the answer already existed in another question, what does this mean: "The second advantage of square bracket notation is when dealing with variable property names." ? We can use custom variable `myControlNumber` for `myForm["myControlNumber" + i]`?

Comment: @ChenghuaYang yes, you can

Answer (score 3):

> I don't know how value[x] evaluate expression.

To evaluate an expression means to substitute all the symbols with corresponding values and apply all (if any) operations to them (and JS does everything for you so you should not think of it any hard ever).

In case of as trivial expression as just `x` - its evaluation equals to the value the variable `x` refers to.

Eg:

```
var x = 'vvv';
alert(value[x]);
```

In this example the `vvv` property of the `value` object will be `alert`ed.